# AMD Phenom 2 x4 955 Pin out

Tags: pin, amd-phenom

I broke 2-3 pins of my AMD Phenom 2 x4 955 Black Edition.

Now, I am trying to find its pin configuration. I cant get its pin out or its data sheet.

I tried using a copper wire. I dropped it in the socket where the broken pin should be and made sure its making contact with the processor. Still my PC wont get back to life.

Is there any possible way to check if my processor is in working condition or not?

Comment: *Is there any possible way to check if my processor is in working condition or not?* **Still my PC wont get back to life** you have your answer there.

Answer (score 0):

I think the only question you asked is: **Is there any possible way to check if my processor is in working condition or not?**

The only way to know if a processor is in working condition is putting it into a socket and trying to make the computer run. The fact that it has 2-3 broken pins renders it unusable and thus **not in working condition** right from the beginning.

Trying to solder/improvise pins would work, but make sure they do correct contact. If that doesn't solve the issue, nothing else will. R.I.P your poor Phenom.